# System.Drawing.Graphics very large images

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, drawing

I'm creating a basic autocad viewer that has to deal with very large images.

I'm using System.Drawing.Graphics to render the images via:

```
Bitmap imageData;

public void Init(string filepath)
{
    imageData = new Bitmap(filepath);
}

public void Render(System.Drawing.Graphics ctx)
{
    ctx.DrawImage(imageData, x, y, w, h);
}
```

One specific file I'm dealing with has about ten 8000x8000 pixel .tif files. Needless to say the above falls pretty well on it's face with an OutOfMemory exception.

The files are compressed to a few megabytes each. Can anyone suggest a better strategy for rendering them?

Comment: I estimate ten 8000x8000 pixel .tif files to be approx. 2.56GB How much memory do you have?

Comment: @Mitch: If I remember right, I read somewhere that the maximum Working Size of a .NET process is 2GB so it it quite logical that this application should fail.

Comment: It has to work on a typical client machine so I can't force .net to otherwise behave differently. I'm looking for a less memory-intensive strategy to render these images. Incidentally, the autocad viewer has no problems (it's rendering is generally a lot slower though for everything else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using .NET 4? If so, you can use Memory Mapped files to "load" the data into memory and only read the bits that you need to render on screen.